# nestjs/cli has npm warning that it does not support node 16.13.1

Tags: node.js, nestjs

When I run npm i @nestjs/cli --save I get the error message shown below. Please let me know how to clear the warnings.

```
npm WARN EBADENGINE Unsupported engine {
 npm WARN EBADENGINE   package: 'lru-cache@9.1.1',
 npm WARN EBADENGINE   required: { node: '14 || >=16.14' },
 npm WARN EBADENGINE   current: { node: 'v16.13.1', npm: '9.5.1' }
 npm WARN EBADENGINE }
```

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

nestjs needs to be on v18. After installation of 18.16.0 - the LTS version, the warning has disappeared.